# Symfony, action accessible by forward only

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony1

Is it possible to prevent direct access to an action in symfony. The action is only accessible by "forward" only. So basically, a way to see if the request is coming from another action.

I'm trying to achieve this because the first action handles plenty of verifications then if it fails, it stays on that action. If it succeed, it will forward to an appropriate action; this action needs to have safe inputs (validated from the first action). In order to keep the code DRY, the second action doesn't need to re-verify all the inputs again.

Then why not doing simply a private method? The second action is sort of a plugin, it's decided on the fly where it's going from the first one, that action has its own set of other future action/template. It makes more sense to simply forward instead of trying to handle plenty of cases that Symfony already takes care of.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you want to achieve with this. Why forward to an action that is not accessible doesn't make sense for me but maybe I found no use-case so far.

Comment: I have added an explanation in the question. Someone already answered though. Thanks

Comment: I think your "second controller" should be a service, maybe you should try it in the future... You can inject e.g. the templating service to your own service if you need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1) Make sure your action isn't accessible by the routing. If you have wildcard routes this will be harder, but you can always add a route which would point the url for your action to a 404 page. Add something like this to your `routing.yml`:

```
disabled_action:
  url: /disabledController/disabledAction
  params: { module: default, action: error404 }
```

2) Check the action stack upon executing your action. The action stack let's you know from which action you were redirected. You can access it within your action using `$this->getController()->getActionStack()`. If the `getSize()` is bigger than `1` (in a default configuration) you we're forwarded.

Comment: This solution is PERFECT. Both ways you proposed are working perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to answer the question instead of asking me why I am doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use referrer parameter available in request

$request->getReferer()  will give you full url of previous action

Comment: The `$request->getReferer()` returns the REFERER header from the HTTP Request. This header cannot be 'trusted', because not all browser send this header (you can configure browsers not to send it), and can also be spoofed easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you're trying to achieve this. Are you looking to have multiple points of access that forward to this action? What if you simply defined a private method (which by default aren't web-accessible) and called it directly from another action?

Comment: I have added an explanation in the question. Someone already answered though. Thanks